# Guzzle POST request from and to PHP with variables

Tags: php, api, ssl, guzzle

I have two parts of PHP code that need to exchange information one way (api). So therefore I have created a PHP file with a guzzle request and an endpoint. The data transferred between the two is not a big secret. Still though, I have a "secret key" I use for authentication between them. At the moment this works fine when sending data through guzzle with a post request and query variables:

```
$guzzle = new Guzzle(['base_uri' => 'https://example.com']);
$response = $guzzle->request('get', '', [
    'query' => [
        'key' => $key
    ],
    'http_errors' => false
]);
```

But when sending it like this exposes the key to "the man in the middle". So my solution is to run it as post request with SSL and Bob would be your uncle. So I changed my code to:

```
$guzzle = new Guzzle(['base_uri' => 'https://example.com']);
$response = $guzzle->request('post', '', [
    'form_params' => [
        'key' => $key
    ],
    'http_errors' => false
]);
```

But, PHP does not recognize the $_POST variables sent like it does with the get request ($_GET). So the question is, how do I get to those variables or what should I change to hide the key through SSL.

Comment: Can you also post the API code in your question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in this case the api is to no significance. But for argument sake: var_dump($_POST); // results in an empty array

Comment: Have you tried to specify the path as `/`?  With just a base URI of `https://example.com` and an _empty_ request path, I’m not to sure this works as intended. Your server might issue a redirect.

Comment: That is a very valid comment. But helas, it's just a simple call to a stand alone page without any redirect or htaccess. Looking at other SO questions/answers it seems more complicated. A post is the same as a get or something. Which is all fine, but I still can't get my variables.